# Change Ringtone in Android

Tags: android, android-widget

I have the following code, and i have a problem regarding changing the ringtone in Android. 
i've red this code should solve my problem (save the changed ringtone):

```
 RingtoneManager .setActualDefaultRingtoneUri( CustomizeActivity.this,
 RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, Uri .parse("Media file uri"));
```

but i don't know where should i place this. PLease help. 
King Regards,

```
button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                String uri=null;

                ****//First URI
                RingtoneManager .setActualDefaultRingtoneUri( CustomizeActivity.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, Uri .parse("Media file uri"));****


                Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
                intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
                if (uri !=null) {
                    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, Uri.parse(uri));

                }else{
                    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, (Uri)null);
                }
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);


            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code on `onActivityResult`.like

```
@Override  
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {  
            return;  
        } else {  
            Uri uri = data  
                    .getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);  
            if (uri != null) {  
                switch (requestCode) {  
                case 1:  
                    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this,  
                            RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, uri);  
                    break;  
                default:  
                    break;  
                }  
            }  

        }  
    }
```

Comment: imrankhan thanks very much, but please inlight me again with one specification in line : "case:Ringtone:", where should i define "Ringtone"  ?